# Trying to use Anaconda to do reverse geocoding, but ran into a couple of issues

Tags: python, anaconda, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to run a reverse geocoding in Anaconda. Here are three questions I have:

1. When I installed -c conda-forge geopandas in my terminal, it shows an error message: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. What should I do with this?
2. I understand that using GeoPandas in Anaconda i'd have to use google, but I don't want to pay for it. Is there any other free API that i can use but also compact with Anaconda.
3. I tried to import reverse_geocode ( a package in Python) in Anaconda, but it gave me a error message: ImportError: No module named future.moves.urllib.request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Probably just a warning: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8512
2. The default provider is Nominatim and can also be selected by:

```
from geopandas.tools.geocoding import reverse_geocode
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

reverse_geocode([Point(-71.0582912,42.3602534)], provider=Nominatim)
```

result:`Boston City Hall, 1, Congress Street, Dock Squ...`

Understanding is based on: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/tools/geocoding.py#L27

3. Install the `future` module: `pip install future`